# Flush entities one by one after ObjectManager:merge()

Tags: php, symfony, doctrine-orm

I have a Doctrine\ORM entity, consisting of new and existing database entities, created from Doctrine ObjectManager:merge(). Before flushing, I want to prevent duplicates (the context is an api where users could send e.g. duplicate city names within the same request).

As mentioned [in this github issue](https://github.com/doctrine/doctrine2/issues/5092#issuecomment-181019136) it is recommended to flush after every persist() operation to be able to query my database for existing records including the ones persisted in this request. How could I do that?

My code is:

```
...
$object = $mapper->map($objectRaw, new $modelClassName());
$object = $em->merge($object);
# I need to intervene here I suppose
$em->flush();
```

I tried:

- the hint mentioned on the github issue that dql would trigger a flush automatically, but after merge() that would imho mean that all new entites would be flushed, which I do not want before having checked for duplicates
- lots of Lifecycle Events combinations, but I think that is not the way, the relevant ones already happened in the merge

It seems that I need a way to flush each entity one by one and do my checks at that time, something like:

1. Store scheduled insertions from UnitOfWork.
2. Clear list of scheduled insertions.
3. Persist and flush every insertion one by one and do my checks.

Or another idea - thank you very much!

**Edit:** Another idea would probably be to simply do my checks and manipulations on the object *before* `$em->merge($object);`. But you would loose the possibility of matching against repositories. So still, the question keeps me busy...